# Where to apply for MSc depending on GPA?

Tags: application, gpa

I am an engineering undergrad in my third year. The question that I am asking might sound like a duplicate but I seek some rough statistics. What classification might be roughly correct for institutions offering MSc degree for their average acceptation GPAs?

To visualize, I do not expect a 2.8/4 average student to be accepted to MIT except extreme cases. Would it be "roughly" correct to make a tabulation as follows:

top-20:   3.7/4

top-50:   3.5/4

top-100:   3.3/4

top-200:  3.0/4

I am aware of that it lacks real statistical information and there are many external factors shaping this kind of generalization, however, it would be helpful for making "realistic" degree applications. Any improvement would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the US since you mentioned MIT? You need to look at the individual departments'/universities' websites and look for their past admission averages.For example [here is MIT](http://www.eecs.mit.edu/academics-admissions/undergraduate-programs/6-p-meng-program/requirements-admissions). Looks like to get into EECS for an MSc they require about 3.27GPA/4.0.

Comment: However, it also matters where you are coming from (easy to get 4.0 in some schools). For more info take a look at [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30157/what-gpa-is-considered-as-competitive-for-top-five-schools-in-engineering-in-us?rq=1).

Comment: I'm talking about world rankings, yet it is irreleveant since US dominates other countries in the top hundred colleges list. That's right. I have a friend who is transferred to my home university. He halved his CGPA in my university despite working harder here. But I think, as it is mentioned in the stackexchange link that you've provided, average acceptance CGPA is not disclosed mostly. Thus, the only reliable material is the comments and conditions of average individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even at the Masters level, graduate admissions are just not that simple and one-dimensional.  GPA is not directly comparable between schools, since different schools have different qualities and different ways of calculating GPA (often even within a single country: GPA is computed many different ways in the US).  Expect your entire record to be scrutinized, along with whatever recommendation letters, essays, etc. that you are also asked to provide.

In short: nobody can tell you where to apply unless they know both you and the programs that you are applying to very well.